# Boolean inside property list (Simple!)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm writing a small application right now and I got problems while reading out a property list...

My exact question is: How can I read out a boolean from the property list? Or better how can I read out this boolean from a NSDictionary?

Thanks, mavrick3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects are stored as NSNumber objects, so to retrieve the BOOL you should use this method:

```
BOOL myBool = [someNSNumberObject boolValue];
```

To retrieve from a dictionary do something like this:

```
BOOl myBool = [[someDictionary objectForKey:@"someKey"] boolValue];
```

Documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/boolValue

Comment: OmG, I spent hours for searching a solution but it was so near... Thank you very much!

Comment: If your plist is in fact coming from `NSUserDefaults`, you can skip the `NSNumber` by using `-[NSUserDefaults boolForKey:]` when reading and `-[NSUserDefaults setBool:forKey:]` when writing.

Answer (score 2):

Try storing the BOOL as a NSNumber ... then adding that to the Dictionary.

A simple example :

```
   BOOL answered = YES;
    NSNumber *answeredAsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:answered];
    [dict setObject:answeredAsNumber forKey:@"isAnswered"];

    BOOL retrievedAnswered = [[dict objectForKey:@"isAnswered"] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

A BOOL should be stored as a [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and you can access the BOOL value by saying

`BOOL myvalue = [aNSNumber boolValue]`